# Is there a java sdk and samples to connect and get Azure AppInsight Service Metrics and quota information from a Java Application?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a java SDK and samples to connect and get **Azure AppInsight Service** Metrics and quota information from a Java Application?

Or are there any exposed rest APIs to call and get the metrics, to integrate and test from a Java application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started#2-add-the-application-insights-sdk-for-java-to-your-project

Answer (score 0):

There is a [REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview) to get the metrics.

First, you need to get your API key and Application ID, details [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID): Nav to azure portal -> go to your application insights -> under configure section, select API Access -> Write down the application id, then click Create API Key, screenshot below, remember write down the key: 
[image]

Second, construct the api url to fetch the metric which you need. Details in this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Metrics).

A simple example is that I want to get the request count in the last 6 hours, the url looks like below(replace the your_Application_ID with your own Application_ID in last step):

```
string URL_requests = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your_Application_ID/metrics/requests/count?timespan=PT6H";
```

I'm not familiar with java, so just use a C# code(I think it's easy to convert to java):

```
string apikey = "your_api_key";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
var req = string.Format(URL_requests);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // get the metric you need
}
else
{
    return response.ReasonPhrase;
}
```